# Possible conflicts of God creating Universe using Big Bang method

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

I'm trying to connect biblical history with science.

**Current Setup:**

1. I used the `Law of conservation of energy`

> The law of conservation of energy states that energy can neither be
> created nor destroyed - only converted from one form of energy to
> another. This means that a system always has the same amount of
> energy, unless it's added from the outside.

God is  `pure spirit`, but every piece of him is an `all-purpose miracle`.

Using the Reverse formula of ***$E = mc^2$*** (Creating energy using matter)  ***$mc^2 = E$*** (Creating matter using energy), and the `all-purpose miracle` to produce energy, He will create matter inside the Universe container.

2. Conflicting timelapse

Scientifically, the universe's age is around 13.7 billion years old. Bible states that God created universe in 6 days.

In this matter, verses in the bible stated that God's 1 day is not 24 hours, but the most significant verse stated is

> God predicted the modern war will have its pause that lasts around half an hour.

This is probably the infamous World War 1 and World War 2, so his `around half an hour` is 21 years (End of first world war: 1918 and the start of 2nd world war: 1939).
This setup is not yet complete, i'm still working on the exact time.

3. Guiding the future Earth

During the creation of Big-Bang, every matter and energy is calculated perfect in order to place the future Galaxies, future Solar System, and future Earth. Any miscalculations will require the `all-purpose miracle`.

Lastly, creation of bacteria (including future animals (including humans)) will also require `all-purpose miracle`

**QUESTION:**

What are the other things that will affect my setup?
Is there anything I missed?
What are the consequences of this setup?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

Everything inside this Universe are all made of 2 things, `Energy` and `Matter`, but there is third thing which is `Spirit`.

This mysterious thing so-called `Spirit` (or `all purpose miracle`) are matterless/energyless, it can't affect anything inside the universe unless it converts into something (either matter or energy)

God (the pure Spirit) can enter this universe and go back to God's realm at will.

In this reasoning, it can travel through anything, and can conjure anything in thin air.

Comment: "Is there anything I missed?" - Reminds me of this joke: https://old.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/eccj2/how_to_draw_an_owl/

Comment: @SurpriseDog I'm not asking for the whole bible content, It's just the very 1 page of it, which is just few lines, just the creation of universe.

Comment: "Consequences of God creating Universe using Big Bang method" ? Well, if the mainline Christian denominations are correct, the answer would be "look around you!"...

Comment: I don’t get your reasoning. The statement that God created universe in 6 days does not imply that the age of the universe was six days. A lot of things happened between the creation and today. So there is no reason to match the 13.7 billion years with God’s six days. Besides that, is that prediction something you just made up (why?) or supposed to be an actual thing of the Bible?

Comment: This is the (unofficial, but officious) theological position of those Christian churches which care about physics, for example the Catholic Church. What did your diligent research reveal about this interpretation, and what details do not satisfy you and need clarification? (And the law of conservation of energy is rather lax at the quantum scale. See [quantum fluctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation). No need for God to pour energy into the universe to trigger the Big Bang.)

Comment: "God predicted the modern war will have its pause that lasts around half an hour." - I am sorry, where that is from?

Comment: "God created x on the nth day" could actually be interpreted as "on the nth day, god tweaked the parameters of the universe such that x would appear some millenia later". Then you've got no temporal problems anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The universe is getting hotter.

God can put in more energy, but he can't take it out. In addition to entropy this means that the universe will become more energetic the more God does miracles. The more energetic things are, the higher the chance of making a mistake that needs a miracle. Then, you need to correct for heating issues. Eventually the universe combusts from cumulative heating.

2. God is shrinking.

God can make matter and energy with all purpose miracle, but that requires a part of him. This means that over short periods of time God gets smaller. Unless God regenerates this means God may one day expend himself.

3. God misses a lot of things since time is so fast.

One second to God is a full day to humans. Assuming God has God-like reflexes, God has a reaction time of 100 ms. At a rate of 25.55 hours per second God cannot react to events that take place in less than two hours. So if there is a mistake then any fix will be about two hours late.

4. Guiding earth is impossible by known quantum mechanics.

Quantum events are thought to be non-deterministic and random. If they are, every second millions of quantum events need to be corrected in the sun and in other places where it is noticeable.

5. Life is not a miracle.

At a molecular level, there is no need for a spirit for bacteria or humans. molecular interactions can explain all observed phenomena, so the requirement of a spirit is not needed.

6. God is bored

This project has been going for 150 thousand years for God. But all of human history has been going for only two months. For the entirety of that thousands of years span God has been correcting minor spin errors on individual atoms to ensure everything is just right. God needs a hobby since doing a single task for longer than human civilization has existed in real life for a few months of entertainment will strain God in ways we can only imagine.

Comment: Damn, you nailed it right. I'll wait for other answers until tomorrow (if any)

Comment: 3 can be disputed. God is almighty, all-knowing, and omnipresent. God should be able to react in time.

Comment: @Otkin: This is a list of ideas for someone writing a story, not a real-world theological debate (I hope?!).  If you mean that (3) might strike some readers as silly, that's fair.

Comment: @PeterCordes 3 is inconsistent with God of Abraham. That's it.

Comment: I believe God can scatter himself everywhere. Though I don't know much how they communicate to each pieces.

Answer (score 3):

You mention a "Universe Container" which I assume is a conceptual box within which conservation of matter/energy is enforced.  Is your all purpose miracle god inside the container or outside?

If It is outside the container, then its only interaction must conserve matter/energy.  It cannot add content to the container, nor remove anything.  From this external position, It can influence how the universe and eventually life evolves only to the extent that the balance is maintained.

It is even worse if It is within the container, since now not only the influence that It manifests must abide by the law, but also the pure spirit, all purpose miracle god itself, must also obey the law.

The challenge here is that you have placed your supreme being/source of design intelligence beneath the authority of your scientific physical laws.  You now have to justify all of creation through the facilities of an almost all-powerful being who still has to obey the rules.

I would suggest that instead of a Universe Container, you need a Universal Operating System.  That way your god doesn't need to use miracles break the rules which the rest of us have to obey.  It just has to override them from a higher permissions level than it has granted us or the rest of reality.

Your god is the sys-op (and maybe the original programmer) of the universe and for it, the operational/physical constraints of the system are just guidelines, not unbreakable laws.

Comment: hi, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

#### If God created the universe then it was not from within the confines of the human perspective.

**God exists outside of time**

2 Peter 3:8–9: ‘But do not forget this one thing, dear friends: With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day. The Lord is not slow in keeping his promise, as some understand slowness. He is patient with you, not wanting anyone to perish, but everyone to come to repentance.’

*The point is that linear time measurement has no meaning.*

**One day of Brahma**

Bg 8:17 - One day of Brahma (kalp) lasts a thousand cycles of the four ages (mahā yug) and his night also extends for the same span of time. The wise who know this understand the reality about day and night.

*This day of Brahma translates as 4.32 billion years. 100 days of Brahma is the life span of the universe*

**There does not even need to be a beginning**

Allow me to introduce Penrose's cyclical universe:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology

Also this is vaguely compatible with Hindu cyclical cosmology. Or maybe one of these can be a "day".

**Conservation of energy isn't necessarily needed**

*In fact mass/energy, as measured by humans, having any meaning whatsoever is contradicted by Maya*

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(religion)

*Many theologies suggest creation ex-nihilo, like the Kalam cosmological argument.*

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam_cosmological_argument

**Everything else**

The above is just the tip of the iceberg as I see it, there is sufficient flexibility in the not-quite-science of spirituality & religion to invent a convincing cosmology but it's not straightforward as there is no correct answer & it's really a matter of individual choice as to how you put these things together.